# Rails 4 or 5, index on "updated_at" column in Postgresql. What it means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 with this:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  fresh_when(etag: @posts, last_modified: @posts.maximum(:updated_at))
end
```

A friend of mine told me that if I'm going to use these methods (stale or fresh_when) "I would need an index on the "updated_at" column".

What does this mean?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index

Comment: Thanks @MikDiet, but what it means?

Answer (score 3):

The goal of an index is to speed up the process of finding records in your database. If you're planning on frequently looking up model records by the `updated_at` field, you should consider adding an index.

Your friend likely told you to add an index to the `updated_at` column because the `fresh_when` makes reference to it. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ConditionalGet/fresh_when

However, in the case of the `fresh_when` method, your record will already be loaded, so you won't see any gain from indexing the `updated_at` field since the record will already be in memory.

Put simply, indexes make database reads faster. The downside is that they slow down writes to the database. Most of the Rails developers I know only index foreign keys for associations because foreign keys are usually an integer, which is relatively cheap to write/index. For example:

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
end
```

`add_index :comments, :post_id`

which should speed up a query like:

`Post.find(:id).comments`

However, if you were to index every field on your model, you may experience faster lookups, but the index would have to be rebuild every time you update your model, so writes to the database would be much slower.

The bottom line is that you should think twice about which fields you index.